# Passing values inside radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, forms, radio-button, haml

I'm using a form that updates a subscription, and allows the user to use the current credit card on file, or use another.  I'm using two radio buttons that allow them to either pass in what's currently saved or pass in new form data.

[image: radio buttons]

Relevant code in my view (HAML):

```
= form_for(@user) do |f| 
  #payment-option
    =f.radio_button :credit_card_attributes, id: 'old_cc_number', checked: true
      # not sure what to put here
    ="Use your current card ending in #{current_user.subscription.credit_card.masked_card_number.slice 15..19}"    

  %br    

  #payment-option
    =f.radio_button :credit_card_attributes, current_user.subscription.credit_card.masked_card_number, id: 'new_cc_number'
    Enter new payment information

    .signup-field-container.new-payment-information{style:'display:none'}
      = f.text_field :credit_card_number, placeholder: "Card Number", class: ' signup-fields card-number', id: 'credit_card_input'
      = f.select(:expiration_month, ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07','08','09','10','11','12'], {prompt: 'MONTH'}, class: 'signup-fields exp-date')
      = f.select(:expiration_year, ['2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021','2022','2023','2024','2025','2026'], {prompt: 'YEAR'}, class: 'signup-fields exp-date')
      = f.number_field :cvv, placeholder: "CVV", class: ' signup-fields cvv'
```

The goal is to make a request to an external API with JSON.

```
current_user.subscription.update_attributes(
  {
    "credit_card_attributes"=>
    {
      "full_number" => credit_card_number,
      "cvv" => cvv,
      "expiration_month" => expiration_month,
      "expiration_year" => expiration_year
    }
  }
)
```

Any advice on how to structure the radio buttons so that I can pass in parameters with values of the currently saved credit card for the first radio button, and pass in parameters with values for a new credit card for the second radio button?  I know the current form structure is a complete mess.  I suspect it's an easy solution, but my inexperience with radio buttons is leaving me scratching my head.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
=f.radio_button :credit_card_attributes, id: 'old_cc_number', value: @old_cc_number checked: true
```

using a value should work... but I don't think you should pass the cc info to the view.

I would set your radio up like this:

```
= form_for(@user) do |f| 
  #payment-option
    =f.radio_button :use_old_cc_number, id: 'old_cc_number', value: true, checked: true
      # not sure what to put here
    ="Use your current card ending in #{current_user.subscription.credit_card.last_four}"    

  %br    

  #payment-option
    =f.radio_button :use_old_cc_number, current_user.subscription.credit_card.masked_card_number, id: 'new_cc_number', value: false
    Enter new payment information
    ...
```

Use the radio button name "use_old_cc_number" and its value true/false to set up your controller logic:

```
def your_controller_method
  ...some logic...

  if params[:use_old_cc_number] == true
    full_number = @current_user.subscription.credit_card
  else
   full_number = params[:credit_card_number]
  end

...make json call...
end
```

And that should work.